# How can I resolve a stale nfs handle?

Tags: debian, nfs

I noticed once when I shut down my home server while my desktop was connected via NFS that I kept getting "stale NFS handle warning" when entering my home dir, this caused issues with some programs that looked in those folders.

How do I resolve this issue without restarting my machine?

Debian Squeeze/Wheezy

Comment: What OS and/or distribution are you running?

Comment: I am using Debian Squeeze

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Debian Squeeze/Wheezy:

Force unmount the local mount

```
umount -f /mnt/dir
```

Then restart nfs

```
/etc/init.d/nfs-common restart
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can force the unmount of a filesystem - so I doubt the above will work.

Comment: umount -f didn't work for me, but umount -lf did!

Answer (score 3):

Try this shell script. Works good for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Purpose:
# Detect Stale File handle and remove it
# Script created: July 29, 2015 by Birgit Ducarroz
# Last modification: --
#

# Detect Stale file handle and write output into a variable and then into a file
mounts=`df 2>&1 | grep 'Stale file handle' |awk '{print ""$2"" }' > NFS_stales.txt`
# Remove : ‘ and ’ characters from the output
sed -r -i 's/://' NFS_stales.txt && sed -r -i 's/‘//' NFS_stales.txt && sed -r -i 's/’//' NFS_stales.txt

# Not used: replace space by a new line
# stales=`cat NFS_stales.txt && sed -r -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/ /\n /g' NFS_stales.txt`

# read NFS_stales.txt output file line by line then unmount stale by stale.
#    IFS='' (or IFS=) prevents leading/trailing whitespace from being trimmed.
#    -r prevents backslash escapes from being interpreted.
#    || [[ -n $line ]] prevents the last line from being ignored if it doesn't end with a \n (since read returns a non-zero exit code when it encounters EOF).

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Unmounting due to NFS Stale file handle: $line"
    umount -fl $line
done < "NFS_stales.txt"
#EOF
```

Comment: Based on my experience it it seems to be a 50:50 change for this not to be enough, and a machine reboot being needed. I am looking forward to see a better script, maybe one to put in the crontab. We encounter this kind of problem very often, with more than one machine per day.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually issue those commands (as `root`):

```
service nis restart
service autofs restart
service nfs restart
service portmap restart
```

You may not need all of those, depending on how your system works.

Comment: Which Distro is this for?